# default apps win10 don't show all options

Tags: notepad++, notepad

I have installed notepad++ and within that set up the file associations. However in Win10 Apps/Features, I am not shown notepad++ as an option for any of the file types such as .txt, only notepad or wordpad or select from the app store.

Do I need a registry hack or what please?

Comment: Thanks DrMoishe Pippik - running notepad++ with admin rights and setting the file associations worked and were reflected in the windows apps&features. I too have noticed how updates to windows often resets file associations which is maddening.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to resolve the issue:

- Run Notepad++ **as Administrator** and try setting the filetype associations again. This is also necessary for 7-Zip and other applications that replace MS default apps. If this does not work:
- Right-click a .txt file and select *Open with*.

[image: Open with dlg]

- Select *Choose another app*.

[image: Select another app dlg]

- If the desired application does not show, select *More apps*.
- Check *Always use this app to open .txt files*.

**OR**

- Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key and type "Def".
- Select *Default Apps* dialog.

[image: Default Apps dlg]

- Select *Choose Default apps by file type*.
- Scroll down to *.txt* and select your application.

[image: Select app by filetype dlg]

**Having said all this, AFTER EACH WINDOWS UPDATE THAT INSTALLS OR UPDATES UWP (newspeak for "Metro") APPS, the default choices are compromised. Then you may see a dialog asking if you still wish to use Notepad++ or prefer the newest greatest app *mirabile* from MS.**

Comment: "EACH TIME WINDOWS UPDATES" - this is an inaccurate statement this only happens if it happens when a feature update is installed

Comment: Read it all: "and installs new Metro apps."

Comment: Your statement is still incorrect.  Every update doesn't reset the user defined default application nor does every update install new UWP applications (they are not called Metro applications on Windows 10)./  Nice Windows 8 screenshots....